# ANDROID: I have a map in my app and it only shows a grid..?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got my API key, given my app internet permission, used the maps library, used the API key in the XML file for the page.

I don't know what else to do, in both the emulator and the phone, it just comes up with a grid for the map and I have no idea why. When I run the app on the phone, however, I AM told that it has Android 2.1 --- Not the Google API which includes maps so I'm wondering if this is an issue?

Has anybody had this problem? Care to quite forcefully kick me in the right direction?

Comment: please post the code and logcat data

Answer (score 0):

Either it is the wrong API key, or the `<uses-permission>` is in the wrong spot (or otherwise malformed).

> When I run the app on the phone, however, I AM told that it has Android 2.1 --- Not the Google API which includes maps so I'm wondering if this is an issue?

If your phone does not have Google Maps, you would not even be able to run your app. I don't think it will even install -- it should get a "missing shared library" installation error.